# User profile properties not updated in a particular web application

Tags: sharepoint-server, user-profile, user-profile-service

User profile properties not updated in a particular web application in a farm, but it is updated in all other applications. The user profile sync job is running fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For new users in OOB People Pickers:

```
stsadm -o setproperty -url "applicationurl/" -pn peoplepicker-onlysearchwithinsitecollection -pv no
```

For users using Last Name:

```
stsadm -o setproperty -url "applicationurl/" -pn peoplepicker-searchadcustomquery -pv (Surname=*{0}*)
```

For new users in People Editor:

```
stsadm -o setproperty -pn peoplepicker-Peopleeditoronlyresolvewithinsitecollection -pv no -url "applicationurl/"
```

The above queries has fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Run `stsadm -o -listolddatabases 0`. If any databases have a date greater than 1 day, run `stsadm -o -deleteolddatabases 0`. This will clear the sweep sync information on the Content Databases, allowing the UPSA -> CDB job to complete successfully.